# What DOM event updates a ReactJS app and how can you force update with plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, dom, loading

I am very new to ReactJS and was wondering the following: On what DOM event, if there even is a standard, does react update the contents of the root container or app container? Is there a way to force this event via a plain Javascript event dispatch? An example of website would be WhatsApp Web. It loads a spinner loader and some event loads to fill out the rest of the elements once loaded.

Comment: You mostly just render the root component to the DOM once, and React takes over from there. If you want to load some data you can do that in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook of your component instead.

Comment: @Tholle To clarify the question a bit, I am NOT writing the react app. I have a react app written by someone else running in browse. I need a way to force rerender or force load components in vanilla JS. hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

you can basically **call `ReactDom.render()` on root element** to rerender everything, its very fast as pointed out here by Dan himself

https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/691301224541503488?lang=en

Comment: Hmm interesting. When I call this, it actually removes all the root container content and DOM nodes. it appears the function takes two parameters locally called e and t (viewed by inspecting the function)

Comment: yes first parameter is component to mount, and second is where to mount it. So basically you might have used this statement somewhere in your app to mount the app initially, you can just call that statement again

Comment: When you say where to mount, its basically a dom element correct? As in a document.getElement... For the first param, Im assuming it should reference the inrernal react element such as “app”. I shouldnt have to rerender each component one by one in the entire app I assume. (Hope)

Comment: Yes.. First is the top level react component.. Second is dom element which u want to be parent of the react component

Comment: I will try this out. Fingers crossed

Comment: So this did not seem to work for following reason (although, I think this is on the right track). Getting this error: https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=191&args[]=%5Bobject%20HTMLDivElement%5DΩ - Ive tried app._reactRootContainer.render(app._reactRootContainer, document.getElementById('app')) and app._reactRootContainer.render(app, document.getElementById('app'))